# Why doesn't APT download the latest version of packages from my local mirror?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt

I've setup a Ubuntu 14.04 apt-mirror on my LAN using [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror_p3). Everything seems to be working OK, except today I noticed in my repo, I have a newer bash version available which apt does not seem to see on my clients (note the `...ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb`. When I download bash from my apt repo, the client downloads `...ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb` instead of the 1.6. Why?

```
# dir ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 574464 Apr  8  2014 ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 575658 Oct  9  2014 ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-7ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 575388 Nov 17 17:53 ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-7ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb
```

On my LAN client:

```
    # aptitude update
    ...

    # aptitude show bash | grep Version
    Version: 4.3-7ubuntu1.5

    # aptitude download bash
    Get: 1 http://MYLANHOST/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main bash amd64 4.3-7ubuntu1.5 [576 kB]
    Fetched 576 kB in 0s (25.3 MB/s)
```

***UPDATE***: showing `apt-cache policy bash`

```
# apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.3-7ubuntu1.5
  Candidate: 4.3-7ubuntu1.5
  Version table:
 *** 4.3-7ubuntu1.5 0
        500 http://MYLANHOST/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://MYLANHOST/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.3-6ubuntu1 0
        500 http://MYLANHOST/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

***UPDATE***: showing timestamps on `Packages.*`

```
# dir ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/                    
total 8224
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 11 05:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Oct 11 05:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6341067 Nov 21 09:30 Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     104 Nov 21  2016 Release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1144628 Nov 21  2016 Packages.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  917444 Nov 21  2016 Packages.bz2

# cat ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep bash
Package: bash
Replaces: bash-completion (<< 20060301-0), bash-doc (<= 2.05-1)
Recommends: bash-completion (>= 20060301-0)
Suggests: bash-doc
Conflicts: bash-completion (<< 20060301-0)
Filename: pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-7ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
...
```

Comment: `apt-cache policy bash`

Comment: question updated to show output.

Comment: refresh `Packages.*` files on repository

Comment: Is this not already done during apt-mirror process? Timestamps on my packages are shown above for the `trusty-updates` directory. Which I assume should show the 1.6 bash version, however it does not.

Comment: Possibly I needed to run `/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh`. I thought this was running through cron, however it seems to have removed the bash 1.6 version. I will have to recheck my mirror setup.